# How to get localized strings by string code, not property name?

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization

In WindowsPhone application i can use localization in this way:

```
string LocalizedString = LocaleResource.MyPreciousString;
```

But can i refer to localized resources by string code, not property name?
I want to do something like that:

```
string LocalizedString = LocaleResource.GetLocalizedStringByCode("MyPreciousString");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so "Use Reflection, Luke"! This code should help:

```
public static string translate(string messageCode)
{
    PropertyInfo info = typeof(Resources.Locale)
        .GetProperty(
            messageCode, 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static
        )
    ;
    return info != null 
        ? info.GetValue(null, null) as string 
        : messageCode
    ;
}
```

So, we can use this method in some Translator class and get localized string by it's code represented as string.